# Display Statistics from metadata in WooCommerce Admin Products list custom column

Tags: php, woocommerce, metadata, counter, admin

Based on [Count Add To Cart clicks and display them in WooCommerce Admin Product list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871535/count-add-to-cart-clicks-and-display-them-in-woocommerce-admin-product-list/76871831#76871831) answer to my previous question, I'm trying to further modify the code to include not only clicks VS sales, but also to divide the two to get a better understanding on how the sales are going.

This is the code I can't manage to get it working:

```
function add_to_cart_click_counter( $product_id ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    $count = (int) $product->get_meta( '_click_counter' );
    $count++;

    $product->update_meta_data( '_click_counter', $count );
    $product->save();
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'count_add_to_cart_clicks', 90, 4 );
function count_add_to_cart_clicks( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null ){

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' ) === 1 ) {

        add_to_cart_click_counter( $product_id );

        if ( $variation_id > 0 ) {
        add_to_cart_click_counter( $variation_id );
        }
    }
}

add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'product_click_count_column' );
function product_click_count_column( $columns ) {

    $columns['click_counter'] = __( 'Clicks &amp; Sold', 'woocommerce' );
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'product_click_count_column_content', 10, 2 );
function product_click_count_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {

        global $product;
        
        if ( $column === 'click_counter' ) { 
        
            if ( $product->get_type() == 'auction' ) return;
            $sold_x_times = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'total_sales', true );
            echo '<span>Sold </span>' . $sold_x_times . '</br><span>Clicks </span>' . (int) $product->get_meta( '_click_counter' );
            echo '<div style="margin-top:20px"></div>';
        
        // everything works except the line below = what I need is statistics based on clicks / sales
        // echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_click_counter' / 'total_sales', true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last function with the following revisited code function:

```php
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'product_click_count_column_content', 10, 2 );
function product_click_count_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $product;

    if ( $column === 'click_counter' && ! $product->is_type('auction') ) {
        $total_sales  = (int) $product->get_total_sales();
        $clicks_count = (int) $product->get_meta('_click_counter');

        printf('<span>%s</span> %d<br><span>%s</span> %d', __('Sold'), $total_sales, __('Clicks'), $clicks_count);
        
        if( $total_sales > 0 && $clicks_count > 0 ) {
            printf('<div style="margin-top:8px">%s %s<div>', __('Stats'), number_format($clicks_count / $total_sales, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.